# get textbox value from javascript for where clause rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following condition on rails view

```
  <% next_value = Product::Detail.find_user.where(B_Code: VariableONE) %>
```

I want to set a value to `VariableONE` from javascript

Comment: What is your question becuase you are already setting next_value to `Product::Detail.find_user.where(B_Code: VariableONE)` which I don't quite understand since `VariableONE` is a `String` of HTML. Please clarify your intended result.

Comment: @engineersmnky sorry, I just confused of my question as well. Can you please have a look now. I updated the question

Comment: You cannot use javascript to set this variable. `erb` is server side and will be interpreted prior to client side JS executing. You could set the value after the page loads using something like `$(document).ready(function(){$("#some_id").val(YOUR_VALUE_HERE);});` but other than that the value would need to be available prior to the page rendering.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky Can't I do something like `<% new_variable = <%= content_tag :span, id: 'some_id') %> %>`

Comment: sure you can but what are you planning on doing with that `html` string afterwards? since you aren't rendering it it will just fall out of scope without usage.

Comment: Can you give any other way I can achieve it an example please? @engineersmnky